# Single public IP but many web servers (confused)

Tags: apache-2.2, iis

I've searched off and on for a few days about this but somehow still haven't found what I'm looking for. Maybe I'm using the wrong search terms so now I'm turning to serverfault.

I have 1 public IP (say 123.123.123.1) but I have the following servers which all use port 80/443:

- Exchange (e-mail via Outlook Anywhere)
- IIS (company website)
- OTRS (company helpdesk)
- Demo website (products)

Now, I'm aware that there is this thing called reverse proxy on Apache. But I wanted to stay "standard" and use IIS. Is there a way to do reverse proxy using IIS (Win2K8R2)? I'm willing to spend a bit of time to study/implement it, but if it's going to take me 2 days to do just that, then I'm sticking with Apache.

Comment: `Name based virtual hosting` and `Server Name Indication`.  Google can fill in the gaps.  Note that the Server Name Indication bit requires relatively recent browsers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you want to know if getting a Reverse Proxy on IIS is difficult.

The short answer is no; it's just not installed in IIS by default. You need URL Rewriting and (optionally) Application Request Routing.

[This IIS Blog Post](http://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/archive/2010/04/01/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr.aspx) and [this article](https://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/659/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing/) has pretty much everything you need to know. Normally I would never do a link-and-run, but the article is pretty much comprehensive, and there's no point in re-inventing the wheel.